# How to use unique validation in Yii 2

Tags: validation, yii2

I want to make usernames and email addresses unique.

I am using yii base to develop my App. It doesnt not work for me.

[image: Username and Email has already been taken]

My Model:

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
            [['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required'],
            [['username', 'email'], 'unique']
     ];
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Userapp();
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post('UserApp'); 
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->validate()) {
        $model->email = $post['email'];
        $model->username = $post['username'];
        $model->password = $model->setPassword($post['password']);
        if($model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: [Custom validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule). Simply search and try solution ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yii2 has a bunch of built in validators [see](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators).

One of which is `unique`

From Yii2 docs.

> // a1 needs to be unique in the column represented by the "a1" attribute
>
> ```
> ['a1', 'unique'],
> ```
>
> // a1 needs to be unique, but column a2 will be used to check the uniqueness 
>        of the a1 value
>
> ```
> ['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => 'a2'],
> ```

Update:

In your rules array, add the unique validator to `email` and `username` like so:

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
        [['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required'],
        [['username', 'email'], 'unique'],
     ];
```

}

Then before saving the model:

```
if(!$model->validate()){
   return false; 
}
```

Update 2:

You are trying to validate the model before any attributes have been assigned. Update your controller code to the following:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Userapp();
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post('UserApp'); 
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
             $model->email = $post['email'];
             $model->username = $post['username'];
             $model->password = $model->setPassword($post['password']);
            if($model->validate() && $model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } 
            else {
                return false; 
             }
          }
   return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
   ]);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i want to validate username and email check in table. If username or email has been taken, it will show some error message.

Comment: there is no error. In my controller i put:
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->validate()) {
....

Answer (score 0):

the idea was to do a re-direction only when $model->save() is true otherwise render back the original model to be created/updated